# Zephir Tutorial Error

Tags: zephir

I try to apply http://zephir-lang.com/tutorial.html .I run this code in my desktop(text_ext directory).

```
zephir init utils
cd utils
```

and `zephir build` results are:

```
baris@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test_ext/utils$ zephir build
Preparing for PHP compilation...
Preparing configuration file...
shtool:mkdir:Error: invalid number of arguments (at least 1 expected)
shtool:mkdir:Hint:  run `./build/shtool mkdir -h' or `man shtool' for details
Compiling...
Installing...
Extension installed!
Add extension=utils.so to your php.ini
Don't forget to restart your web server
```

`php -v` command

```
PHP 5.5.8-3+sury.org~saucy+2 (cli) (built: Jan 29 2014 13:30:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

In result, "utils.so" is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. 
Utils is not an acceptable name.Because, "i" transform to "İ", in compilation.

Use the latin chars ! (when uppercase)